# register_post_status - show_in_admin_all_list & show_in_admin_status_list does not affect query

Tags: sql

In the `register_post_status`, I've already disabled
`show_in_admin_all_list` & `show_in_admin_status_list` for my custom status `my_hidden_status`

However, from the query log the post_status `my_hidden_status` is still not being filtered out (when loading edit.php)

e.g.

```
SELECT post_status, COUNT( * ) AS num_posts FROM st_posts WHERE
post_type = 'my_cpt' GROUP BY post_status;
```

The post_status I wanted to filter is actually over 90% of my CPT, so
if the query is rewritten as

```
SELECT post_status, COUNT( * ) AS num_posts FROM st_posts WHERE
post_type = 'my_cpt' AND post_status != 'my_hidden_status' GROUP BY
post_status;
```

It can greatly improve performance.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5):

> ***TL;DR:*** It's not a bug (*as we generally understand it*), rather it's a feature that was **never fully implemented** in WordPress.

---

### Status of `register_post_status()`

`register_post_status()` function was never fully implemented in WordPress. If you check WordPress [Codex entry for register_post_status() function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_status), you'll see it's clearly mentioned in a notice:

> **NOTICE:**
>
> This function does NOT add the registered post status to the admin panel. This functionality is **pending future development**. Please refer to  [Trac Ticket #12706](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12706) . Consider the action hook  [post_submitbox_misc_actions](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L183)  for adding this parameter.

Also, if you visit the [Related Ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12706), you'll see that the discussion to implement it fully is going on for over 8 years now (starting from March 2010)! However, since WordPress is open source community driven software & there weren't a lot of volunteers willing to work on this feature, it's still pending proper implementation.

The [Trac Ticket #12706](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12706) states the following in the description:

> A developer should be able to register a custom post status using **register_post_status()**. The admin UI (including post submit box and quick edit) **should reflect this new custom post status**. Furthermore, there are many hard-coded references to 'draft' and 'pending' statuses in core that should properly use the post status API.
>
> **All existing arguments to register_post_status() should be fully implemented**, should also support per-post-type arguments. As things get implemented across core, there will likely be a need for supporting capabilities and bits of API.

Now if you look at the WordPress core CODE, you'll see that this description is still valid. That means:

- The admin UI (including post submit box and quick edit) **doesn't reflect custom post status**. Check [this part of the CODE](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/cd4c960a6c17e683bcc76f1efaadcb272955bb83/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L91-L113) in core:

  ```
  <?php _e( 'Status:' ); ?> <span id="post-status-display">
  <?php
      switch ( $post->post_status ) {
          case 'private':
              _e( 'Privately Published' );
              break;
          case 'publish':
              _e( 'Published' );
              break;
          case 'future':
              _e( 'Scheduled' );
              break;
          case 'pending':
              _e( 'Pending Review' );
              break;
          case 'draft':
          case 'auto-draft':
              _e( 'Draft' );
              break;
      }
  ?>
  </span>
  ```

  The CODE contains **no action / filter hook for any custom post status** or for any modification whatsoever. So the only logical way at the moment is to use some JavaScript to alter the UI implementation until this feature is implemented in WordPress core.
- All existing arguments to ***register_post_status()* is not yet  fully implemented** & hence may look buggy.
- And a lot more discussion & work is needed for the full implementation of the Post Status API.

### What to do about this Lack of Feature or Bug?

Call it a lack of feature or call it a bug, the fact remains: there's a lot more work that needs to be done to complete the Post Status API. 
So if this is too important for you, it's better to join in the discussion in the Support Ticket mentioned above to expedite the development process.

Although the entire development process will need a lot of voluntary work, you can still comment on it about the argument `show_in_admin_all_list` not affecting the query, so that at least this part of the anomaly can be improved earlier than the rest of the Status API.

### What to do until core doesn't implement the features properly?

As it is now, `show_in_admin_all_list` argument only affects the `All(*)` status header part of the All Posts Listing, for example:

[image: All Posts Listing Status Header (All Posts Selected)]

<sub>**Image-1:** All Posts Listing Status Header (All Posts Selected)</sub>

However, it doesn't affect the posts that appear in the list (although it should).

To make sure that posts with your custom status `my_hidden_status` doesn't appear in the list as well, you need to set the `public` argument to `false`.

This will make the `register_post_status()` function call look like the following:

```
register_post_status( 'my_hidden_status', array(
    'label'                     => _x( 'My Hidden Status', 'post' ),
    'public'                    => false,
    'show_in_admin_all_list'    => false, 
    'show_in_admin_status_list' => false,
    'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'My Hidden Status <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'My Hidden Status <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
) );
```

This will show the correct count in `All(*)` status header and also remove the posts with `my_hidden_status` from the `All Posts` or `All {custom_post_type}` listing.

Of course, this will essentially make posts with `my_hidden_status` inaccessible from WordPress Admin Panel. If that was the intent, then fine, otherwise, you may use the `show_in_admin_status_list` to show the posts with `my_hidden_status` in a separate listing header:

```
register_post_status( 'my_hidden_status', array(
    'label'                     => _x( 'My Hidden Status', 'post' ),
    'public'                    => false,
    'show_in_admin_all_list'    => false, 
    'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
    'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'My Hidden Status <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'My Hidden Status <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
) );
```

This will show the Post Lists with the status `my_hidden_status` in a separate header like the following:

[image: All Posts Listing Status Header (Custom Status Selected)]

<sub>**Image-2:** All Posts Listing Status Header (Custom Status Selected)</sub>

### DB Query Optimization Issue:

The related DB Query comes from `wp_count_posts()` function in `wp-includes/post.php` file. If you take a look at the [related CODE](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c9dce0606b0d7e6f494d4abe7b193ac046a322cd/wp-includes/post.php#L2457-L2467), you'll see that the arguments from `register_post_status()` function are not implemented there. Also, there's no way to filter or extend this part of the core CODE either:

```
$query = "SELECT post_status, COUNT( * ) AS num_posts FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = %s";
if ( 'readable' == $perm && is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $type );
    if ( ! current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->read_private_posts ) ) {
        $query .= $wpdb->prepare(
            " AND (post_status != 'private' OR ( post_author = %d AND post_status = 'private' ))",
            get_current_user_id()
        );
    }
}
$query .= ' GROUP BY post_status';
```

Unless both `show_in_admin_all_list` and `show_in_admin_status_list` are set to `false` for a particular status, related posts shouldn't be removed from the query anyway. Otherwise WordPress will not be able to generate the proper `status header` (as shown in image-2).

However, in the case where both `show_in_admin_all_list` and `show_in_admin_status_list` are set to `false`, WordPress doesn't need the count information for that custom status. So logically in this case you'll have a little query performance improvement with `AND post_status != 'my_hidden_status'` part, if you have a large number of posts (like Millions) and most of your posts (as you said 90%) are from that custom  status.

Still, there are two reasons why core may not update this part of the CODE even though there may be a little performance gain in your particular case:

1. **WordPress Database uses an index named `type_status_date`** that indexes `wp-posts` table entries based on `post_type`, `post_status`, `post_date` and `ID` fields. **So queries are fast enough even without the `AND post_status != 'my_hidden_status'` part**.

   I've tested with 15K+ posts and it only takes a few milliseconds. Check [this MySQL Document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html) for more information on GROUP BY Optimization with index. With some tweaks to MySQL index, you may even get better results without even changing WP Core. For example, adding another index with `post_type` and `post_status` column may give you a few milliseconds gain.
2. Even though adding `AND post_status != 'my_hidden_status'` may make the query faster (merely by milliseconds) in your particular case, WordPress still may not update it, because WordPress will have to **consider the possibility where a hidden custom status has only a few posts**. In those cases, adding `AND post_status != 'my_hidden_status'` will actually make the query results a bit slower (only by a few milliseconds).

So considering everything, WordPress may or may not update the query with `AND post_status != 'my_hidden_status'` when both `show_in_admin_all_list` and `show_in_admin_status_list` are set to `false` for a custom status. However, in my opinion, at least making the related query filterable will improve the flexibility for the developers.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a bug? It's doing a little more work than it has to, but it's not resulting in any unexpected output, and it avoids potential problems with other site setups. So I would say no (mostly).

The query in question serves to count the number of posts found before displaying them on the edit screen. It counts all posts by status so that it has these numbers handy if the page needs them later.

My hunch is that the query was kept simple on purpose to prevent the possibility of multiple little-used post statuses clogging and slowing down the query. For example, testing on phpMyAdmin, the base query took 0.0011 seconds with around 300 posts. Adding clauses to filter out 5 unused or little-used post statuses raised the time to 0.0024.

In your situation, you're correct that filtering out 90% of potential results would speed up the query. You could try filtering it with the [query filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query/).

As a side note: while researching this I noticed that if `"public" => true` in `register_post_status`, it overrides the `show_in_admin_all_list` value and displays posts with that status on the edit screen. I'd call that part a bug, since in other `register_*` functions the more specific args tend to override the `public` arg.

Answer (score 1):

The query you are looking to filter is actually called by `wp_count_posts` function. Only way to filter this query is by using `query` filter (found inside `wpdb` class `query` method).

As the filter `query` is used for all of the mysql queries called with `$wpdb` instance, it would be better to register your filter from the exact place you need it. For that, add your filter on `load-edit.php` action.

```
/* register the filter from edit.php page (works for all post types) */
add_action('load-edit.php', 'wpse_initiate_filter');
function wpse_initiate_filter($query) {
    add_filter('query', 'wpse_filter_posts_count_query');
}

/* modify original query to filter out my_hidden_status */
function wpse_filter_posts_count_query($query) {
    if (strpos($query, 'SELECT post_status') === 0) {
        $query = str_replace(" GROUP BY", " AND post_status != 'my_hidden_status' GROUP BY", $query);
    }
    return $query;
}
```